# Find scalar interval containing maximum elements from population A and zero elements from population B

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, intervals

Given two large sets A and B of scalar (floating point) values, what algorithm would you use to find the (scalar) range [x0,x1] containing zero elements from B and the maximum number of elements from A?

Is sorting complexity (O(n log n)) unavoidable?

Comment: Could you add an example, along with any existing code/approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single list with all values, where each value is marked with two counts: one count that relates to set A, and another that relates to set B. Initially these counts are 1 and 0, when the value comes from set A, and 0 and 1 when the value comes from set B. So entries in this list could be tuples (value, countA, countB). This operation is O(n).

Sort these tuples. O(nlogn)

Merge tuples with duplicate values into one tuple, and accumulate the values in the corresponding counters, so that the tuple tells us how many times the value occurs in set A and how many times in set B. O(n)

Traverse this list in sorted order and maintain the largest sum of counts for countA of a series of adjacent tuples where countB is always 0, and the minimum and maximum value of that range. O(n)

The sorting is the determining factor of the time complexity: O(nlogn).

Answer (score 1):

Sort both A and B in O(|A| log |A| + |B| log |B|). Then apply the following algorithm, which has complexity O(|A| + |B|):

```
i = j = k = 0
best_interval = (0, 1)

while i < len(B) - 1:
    lo = B[i]
    hi = B[i+1]
    
    j = k    # We can skip ahead from last iteration.
    while j < len(A) and A[j] <= lo:
        j += 1

    k = j   # We can skip ahead from the above loop.
    while k < len(A) and A[k] < hi:
        k += 1

    if k - j > best_interval[1] - best_interval[0]:
        best_interval = (j, k)
    
    i += 1

x0 = A[best_interval[0]]
x1 = A[best_interval[1]-1]
```

It may look quadratic at a first inspection but note we never decrease `j` and `k` - it really is just a linear scan with three pointers.